# Open (read, write) a file in same directory as main app - python/kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Is there any easy method for opening the text file if you are running your app from the same directory? I can't seem to find anything easy. 
I am asking because you can do that with most of the things in kivy (for image: "name.png", for .kv: load_kv("name.kv") and so on) and I don't understand why it wouldn't be similar with finding a text document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get script's path with:

```
import os, sys
os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

so to refer to files in the same dir you would do:

```
fullpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'filename.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `open('filename')` - the path is relative, so if its in the same directory you don't have to do anything special.

If this appears not to work, perhaps it isn't your syntax that is the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, really sad that it doesn't. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Right, but it *should* work as described, so you need to explain what's wrong if you want help.

Comment: I used it like this: with open("filename.txt", "r") as file: ...   but it said that file does not exist

Comment: So check your assumptions - there are two obvious ones, first that the directory the script is in is the one you think, and second that the file does, in fact, exist. Probably one of these is wrong.